# How to make autocomplete dropdown list appear only at the bottom and define the number of visible results

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I added an autocomplete textView to my app
It works great, just as i want, but

now i want to say that the maximum *visible* results is 3, and that it'd be always at the bottom of the textview (The textview itself is in the middle of the screen always)

How do i do that ?

Comment: Can you explain a bit further what do you mean by `that it'd be always at the bottom of the textview`?

Comment: my textview is in the middle of the screen, and sometimes the results window shows above the textview, instead of below it , how do i make it show always only below it ?

Answer (score 0):

I remember having messed with that a time ago, and all I was able to find is a kind of workaround I didn't like too much for this, since there's no native method for that, but should work. Basically, it consists on calling `.setDropDownHeight(int height)` method.

As you may see, what you provide is a **height**, so you're not specifying the number of items. So you need to take the height of one of the rows and set the height of your dropdownlist to: `number_of_items * height`.

```
yourAutoCompleteTV.setDropDownHeight(your_layout_view.getHeight() * 3);
```

For the second problem problem, I think this is a space problem within your layout. You'll probably have to make yourself sure that there is always enough space below your `TextView` to show all the suggestions and it will open always downwards, so simply tune up your layout for this.

Comment: I do not want to show *just* 3 results, i want to show all the results, except if it is beyond 3, i want the user to scroll, rather than display 10 results on view that are not scrollable, and cover the entire screen

Comment: You should edit your former question and add the Scrolling part since it changes completely the context. I edited my answer.

Comment: i wrote that originally in the answer, that i want only 3 results visible, i did not say i did not want the other results to be not available